# Sort HTML attributes based on Alphabetical order

Tags: html

Is there  a tool for sorting HTML attributes inside elements in Alphabetical order?

Similar to https://xmlsorter.codeplex.com/ for sorting xml files.

Comment: Try http://prettydiff.com/?m=beautify&l=html to beautify your HTML code.

Comment: I'd be interested to see if there's a package available for Sublime/Atom for this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use http://prettydiff.com/?m=beautify&l=html for your HTML code. 
 It will beautify your HTML code. it will sort your HTML attributes.

**Before:**
 [image]

**After:**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[HTML Tidy](http://www.html-tidy.org/)’s `--sort-attributes` option will sort attributes alphanumerically.